# Docker and asp.net core minimize distribution by using "scratch" image?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

Microsoft guidance on running asp.net core projects via a Docker container advocate copying our program files to the microsoft/aspnetcore image in our Dockerfile.

We are using image save and image load commands to distribute our code changes to a test server.

This means the image is quite large and harder to distribute.

Would it be possible to use the "scratch" image, copy our files to it and then via docker-compose bring in the microsoft/aspnetcore image and then our program files image built using "scratch" image?

In this way our own code image is tiny and can easily be distributed via image save and image load commands.

I've tried it and am getting the following error:
"ERROR: for myapp Cannot start service myapp: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"dotnet\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown"

compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  postgresserver:
     image: postgres:alpine
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 5432:5432
     environment:
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: XXXX
     volumes:
       - /var/lib/myapp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     networks:
       - myapp-network

  aspnetcoreruntime:
     image: microsoft/aspnetcore
     working_dir: /app    

  myapp:
     image: mycorp/myapp:v8.0.0-alpha.2
     restart: always
     ports:
       - 7575:7575
     volumes:
       - /var/lib:/var/lib
     environment:
        myapp_USE_URLS: http://*:7575
        myapp_DB_CONNECTION: User ID=postgres;Password=letmein;Host=postgresserver;Port=5432;Database=myapp;Pooling=true;  
        myapp_FOLDER_USER_FILES: /var/lib/myapp/files/user    
        myapp_FOLDER_BACKUP_FILES: /var/lib/myapp/files/backup
     build:
       context: ./myappdocker
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     links:
       - postgresserver
     depends_on:
       - "postgresserver"
       - "aspnetcoreruntime"
     networks:
       - myapp-network

networks:
  myapp-network:
     driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you also share your dockerfile? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "scratch" image. Can you clarify?

Comment: Scratch is the official "empty" base image from Docker

Answer (score 5):

Let me start by saying I don't recommend trying to use "scratch". The image may be a few hundred MB right now, but that is for good reason: the image contains all .NET Core prerequisites, enables a few network settings by default to make deployment easier, and contains the ASP.NET Core runtime that is (1) pre-optimized for Linux using a tool called `crossgen` and (2) serviced regularly with security patches.

If size is your primary concern, checkout https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/issues/833. In ASP.NET Core 2.1, there should be an image based on Alpine Linux, which will be smaller than the current base: Debian Linux.

---

That said, here is what you would need to use "scratch" as your base.

1. Prepare your own base Docker image

If you want to base this on "scratch", you need to ensure you have all of .NET Core's native dependencies present. See https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md. This includes things like `libcurl3`, `libssl`, `libuuid`, and others.

2. Prepare a self-contained deployment.

Self-contained deployment means the output of `dotnet publish` will contain almost all files needed to run your app. This output will be quite large as it includes a copy of all the System.*.dll files that make up .NET Core *and* all Microsoft.AspNetCore.*.dll files. To prepare a self-contained application, you need to:

- Set the RuntimeIdentifier in your .csproj file

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```
- Execute `dotnet publish --self-contained --output ./publish/ --configuration Release`
- Copy `./publish/` into your Docker image
- When using self-contained deployment, it will generate a Linux executable for you to launch your app. Execute `./publish/my-app` instead of `dotnet ./publish/my-app.dll`.

You can also condense the first 2 steps to one action with `dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64`. For more details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

3. Setup ASP.NET Core to expose `0.0.0.0`. By default, ASP.NET Core only binds to localhost. In Docker, this means you must change this to bind to `IPAny` in order to access the web server from outside the Docker container. You can do this in a variety of ways, but the simplest is to set the environment variable `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80`
4. (Optional) Finally, consider pre-optimizing your application using a tool called "crossgen". For large applications, it can reduce startup time of your application time by 15-30 seconds. `crossgen` pre-JITs your *.dll assemblies. See https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/v2.0.5/Documentation/building/crossgen.md for more details.

---

There is one more thing to consider here. By building your own image on "scratch", you lose on potential disk-space savings if you have more than one application on the server running .NET Core. If you had two or three apps all using `microsoft/aspnetcore` as the base, Docker only keeps one copy of `microsoft/aspnetcore`. If you based these two or three apps on scratch, you will end up using more disk space because most of what goes into each image will be duplicated content: the ASP.NET Core runtime. Your program files are typically the smaller part in terms of file-size in what is required to run a .NET Core app.

Comment: I see what you are suggesting but it's orthogonal to what I want to do: I don't want to eliminate the official Microsoft runtime image, I simply want a separate image containing only my code layered on top of it.  I.E. I want to start with microsoft/aspnetcore and layer on top another image that is only my executables that I build.  In this way I can distribute my image more easily. (I'm saving images on my dev station via image save and uploading and then loading them via image load at the server for testing, I don't' want to upload a 300mb file every time)

Comment: Oh, I see what you are asking now. This wasn't clear from the question. Might be good to mention that you're trying to use `docker save`/`docker load`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about mentioned guidance, but if you look into official [dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples) and check [Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/blob/master/aspnetapp/Dockerfile), you will see that [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) is using:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
```

so yes, one of steps do copy of all program files, but docker images is building only on the final stage.

Comment: I'm sorry but how does this relate to what I'm asking about exactly?

Comment: @JohnC based on `copying our program files -> This means the image is quite large and harder to distribute.` My point is that multi-stage builds eliminate this problem.

Comment: Ok, I know that, that's not really my issue here.  I'm trying to do a multi stage build with a very minimal image for my own program files so I can have a really small image to update when changes need to be made.  That's my issue.  I'm not sure how else to word it, perhaps I'm not understanding this issue.